# Not working "+" in grep regex syntax

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Trying:
`grep '.*' file1`

Output:
`file nu-mber o-ne
second string`

Trying: `grep '.+' file1`

Output is absent

Why plus is not working?

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](/q/119905)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) you're using an extended regular expression:

```
grep -E '.+' file1
```

The standard [*Basic Regular Expression*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (as used by `grep` without `-E`) equivalent of the [*Extended Regular Expression*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) `+` operator is `\{1,\}` though some implementations (like GNU's) also recognise `\+` for that as an extension (and you can always use `..*`).

(Note that in this particular case `grep -E .+` is equivalent to `grep -E .` as you're looking for substrings matching the regex when not using the `-x` option. On many systems `egrep` is provided as an equivalent command to `grep -E`, but as [Graeme](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/48083/graeme) [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316381/not-working-in-grep-regex-syntax#comment556099_316382) this is [obsolete](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/egrep.html).)

Comment: Thx a lot. After 12 minutes your answer will be the best

Comment: Note that `egrep` is considered to be obsolete, so `grep -E` is preferred - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/egrep.html. Not that there is any sign of it disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep (default on Ubuntu) you can also enable extended behavior with a backslash. Eg:

```
grep '.\+' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe + is an extended regular expression metacharacter.  Try using `egrep`.